# Reversing Arris BGW210 firmware

Tags: firmware

## TL;DR:

Trying to mount extracted ubi file system onto /dev/mtd0 gives me the error:

```
libscan: scanning eraseblock 323 -- 100 % complete  
ubiformat: 324 eraseblocks are supposedly empty
ubiformat: error!: file "340D04.ubi" (size 42467348 bytes) is not multiple of eraseblock size (131072 bytes)
           error 0 (Success)
```

How do I get that thing flashed?

## Longer version:

I am looking to reverse the firmware for an Arris modem firmware, comparing older versions of the firmware to newer ones. I want to get access to the webroot of the little web server that runs the firmware because I think there is a bug in it.

In this older version, binwalk gives me this:

```
> binwalk spTurquoise210-700_1.6.9.bin

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
544           0x220           Certificate in DER format (x509 v3), header length: 4, sequence length: 985
1533          0x5FD           Certificate in DER format (x509 v3), header length: 4, sequence length: 1246
3332          0xD04           JFFS2 filesystem, little endian
3411204       0x340D04        UBI erase count header, version: 1, EC: 0x0, VID header offset: 0x800, data offset: 0x1000
```

Extracting this `binwalk -e spTurquoise210-700_1.6.9.bin` yields:

```
total 166M
drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root    4.0K Mar  5 16:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 michael michael 4.0K Mar  5 16:10 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     43M Mar  5 16:10 220.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     39M Mar  5 16:10 340D04.ubi
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     43M Mar  5 16:10 5FD.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     43M Mar  5 16:10 D04.jffs2
drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root    4.0K Mar  5 16:10 jffs2-root
```

The contents of jffs2-root don't reveal the webroot. I have mounted the D04.jffs2 image, and it appears to be identical to the extracted jffs2-root directory contents. It appears to be the upgrader that flashes the firmware.

So, I figure I'll check the 340D04.ubi image. To mount that and check it, I:

```
> rmmod mtdram
> du -sk 340D04.ubi
39812   340D04.ubi
> modprobe mtdram total_size=39812
> flash_erase /dev/mtd0 0 0
> ubiformat /dev/mtd0 -f 340D04.ubi
```

That's where I've hit a problem. The output of the ubiformat command is:

```
libscan: scanning eraseblock 323 -- 100 % complete  
ubiformat: 324 eraseblocks are supposedly empty
ubiformat: error!: file "340D04.ubi" (size 42467348 bytes) is not multiple of eraseblock size (131072 bytes)
           error 0 (Success)
```

I cannot figure out how to flash the ubi file system onto the mtd0 device so I can (later) mount it.

## Images:

- [v1.6.9](http://gateway.c01.sbcglobal.net/firmware/001E46/BGW210-700_1.6.9/spTurquoise210-700_1.6.9.bin)
- [v1.8.19](http://gateway.c01.sbcglobal.net/firmware/001E46/BGW210-700_1.8.18/spTurquoise210-700_1.8.18.bin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ubireader_extract_files from https://github.com/jrspruitt/ubi_reader can extract the UBI if it is padded with zeroes to the expected size.